# Customizing mplfinance plot python

Tags: python, charts

Trying to create price chart(something like TradingView chart). Most of the code i already figure out and it seems working but result is not what i want to see. [image]

As you see a lot of white space around a chart and label Price and Volume is not right side, so is there is away to remove white space and move labels on left side? Beside is there away to change background to white?

```
import pandas as pd
import mplfinance as mpf

chartData = {
         'o': [5.589310029183743, 5.610726267831264, 5.6097540855407715, 5.594677448272705, 5.564507322870441, 5.490811827389135], 
         'c': [5.610726267831264, 5.6097540855407715, 5.594677448272705, 5.564507322870441, 5.490811827389135, 5.49099588394165], 
         'h': [5.610831260681152, 5.610726267831264, 5.6097540855407715, 5.594677448272705, 5.564507322870441, 5.49099588394165], 
         'l': [5.57621750831604, 5.608160018920898, 5.582586765289307, 5.5580267906188965, 5.485752105712891, 5.490811827389135], 
         'v': [90.34457968175411, 5.964259386062622, 27.667950868606567, 101.91513729095459, 273.24095344543457, 4.425440788269043], 
         't': [1625720400, 1625721000, 1625721600, 1625722200, 1625722800, 1625723400]}

df: DataFrame = pd.DataFrame(chartData)
df.columns = ['Open', 'Close', 'High', 'Low', 'Volume', 'Date']
data = df.loc[:, ['Open', 'Close', 'High', 'Low', 'Volume', 'Date']]
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'], unit='s', origin='unix')
data.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(data['Date'])

fg1, _ = mpf.plot(data, type='candle',
              title="PolyVertex Price",
              ylabel='Price',
              ylabel_lower='Volume',
              figsize=(20,10),
              returnfig=True,
              style='yahoo',
              volume=True,)

fg1.savefig('text1.jpg')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As you see a lot of white space around a chart and label Price and Volume is not right side, so is there is away to remove white space and move labels on left side? Beside is there away to change background to white?

- Removing extra white space:  Use the [**`scale_padding`** kwarg](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/issues/212#issuecomment-655603896)
- Price and Volume labels on left/right, and the background color, are both part of the [**mplfinance style**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/styles.ipynb).  Therefore, to change these, you need to *create your own* custom style:

  ```py
  customstyle = mpf.make_mpf_style(base_mpf_style='yahoo',
                                   y_on_right=False,
                                   facecolor='w')

  fg1, _ = mpf.plot(data, type='candle',
              title="PolyVertex Price",
              ylabel='Price',
              ylabel_lower='Volume',
              figsize=(20,10),
              returnfig=True,
              style=customstyle,    # use `customstyle`
              volume=True,)
  ```